# How to unsubscribe an email address from a Facebook conversation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Facebook lets you add raw email addresses to conversations even if they're not registered with Facebook accounts.

As far as I can tell, there's no way…

- …for the person who owns the email address to remove themself from the conversation (there's no unsubscribe link, replying with "unsubscribe" or "remove me" don't do the trick either).
- …for the conversation starter to remove the email address from the conversation.

What am I missing?